# Instance member 'navigationItem' cannot be used on type 'MainViewController'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8

Can't seem to get out of this funk with xcode8:

Compilation fails with the message: Instance member 'navigationItem' cannot be used on type 'MainViewController'

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

    private static var __once: () = {
                let loginButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
                MainViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = loginButton
        }()
```

Here is the function that calls this:

```
func setupRightBarButtonItem() {
            struct Static {
                static var onceToken: Int = 0
            }

            _ = MainViewController.__once

            if (AWSIdentityManager.default().isLoggedIn) {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.title =     NSLocalizedString("Sign-Out", comment: "Label for the logout button.")
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.action =     #selector(MainViewController.handleLogout)
            }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This can't work because, as the message says yo can't use an instance property on a class type

Comment: I'm trying to set up AWA SES and get some source code generated from their template aws-my-sample-app-ios-swift v0.3 working.

Comment: Ok, well whoever wrote their template shouldn't be allowed near Swift if that is what they are putting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create the right bar button item the first time `setupRightBarButtonItem` is called, but I am not sure where you came up with this code.

The message is pretty clear, `navigationItem` is a instance property and you are trying to use it as a class property.

Why not use the much more straight-forward:

```
func setupRightBarButtonItem() {

    if navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem == nil {       
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
            UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: .done, target: self, action: nil)    
    }

    if (AWSIdentityManager.default().isLoggedIn) {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.title =     NSLocalizedString("Sign-Out", comment: "Label for the logout button.")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.action =     #selector(MainViewController.handleLogout)
    } 
    // You probably need an `else` clause here to update the button if the user isn't logged in?
}
```